# Details of proof by contradiction

Tags: proof-writing

I realize this is pretty basic but recently became unsure of how to justify proof by contradiction. Is it that case that I can show $A\Rightarrow B$ by assuming $A$ and NOT $B$, and showing this leads to a contradiction? How can this be justified?

Also, let's say I want to show $A$ and $B$ imply $C$. Is it sufficient to show $A, B$ and NOT $C$ leads to a contradiction? Seems this would not be the case, as a contrapositive would be NOT $C$ implies NOT $A$ OR NOT $B$.

Thanks!

Comment: Proof by [contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction).

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the calculus of logic (e.g. Don't know how to negate the proposition "S and T implies Z"). Hence why I am asking basic questions. A response with some references to basic logic books or a summary of the basic computations necessary would be far more useful to me

Comment: That's why you need to be very detailed in your questions. We cannot guess how much you do or do not understand. I also assume you did not actually read the article since the "Principle" section gives an overview using simple words.

Comment: Its best not to accept answers quite so quickly. I usually wait a day or two before accepting any answers, or even up to a week. This makes people more likely to give their own unique answer to the question, with their own unique spin, and this can be very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prove by contradiction that ($A$ AND $B$)$\implies C$, you assume that $A$ AND $B$ AND (NOT $C$) and show that this leads to a contradiction. Here's why:

$a\implies b$ means $b$ OR (NOT $a$). So [($A$ AND $B$)$\implies C$] means [$C$ OR (NOT ($A$ AND $B$))] ie [$C$ OR (NOT $A$) OR (NOT $B$)]. If you negate this, you get $A$ AND $B$ AND (NOT $C$).

Comment: Thanks very much, this is exactly what I was hoping for! Do you know of any basic texts or references so I can see how to interpret implications as AND/OR statements?

Answer (score 2):

I write $\top$ for *true* and $\bot$ for *false*. The basic principle is that to prove $\varphi$, it suffices to:

- assume $\neg \varphi,$
- and then derive $\bot$ (i.e. a contradiction).

Intuitively, this works because (and only because) it is a theorem of Boolean algebra that for all $\varphi \in \{\top,\bot\}$, we have: $$\varphi = (\neg \varphi \rightarrow \bot).$$

This means that to prove $\alpha \rightarrow \beta$, it suffices to assume $\neg(\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$ and derive $\bot$. But some basic Boolean algebra tells us that:

$$\neg(\alpha \rightarrow \beta) = \neg(\neg\alpha \vee \beta) = \neg \neg \alpha \wedge \neg \beta = \alpha \wedge \neg \beta.$$

So assuming $\neg(\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$ is the same as assuming $\alpha$ and $\neg \beta$. Hence, to prove $\alpha \rightarrow \beta$, you should assume $\alpha$ and $\neg \beta$, and attempt to derive $\bot$.

Answer (score 2):

A and NOT B leading to a contradiction, means:

A and NOT B simultaneous can not both be, means:

If A occurs, it will be impossible for NOT B to occur, means:

If A occurs, then B must occur, means:

A $\implies$ B.

===

"Also, let's say I want to show A and B imply C. Is it sufficient to show A,B and NOT C leads to a contradiction?"

Yes.  By the same reasons.

=====

"Seems this would not be the case, as a contrapositive would be NOT C implies NOT A OR NOT B."

This is consistent.  You can prove $(A \& B) \implies C$ in one of three ways:

1) directly:  Assume $A$ and $B$ and show directly that $C$ must follow.

2) contradiction Assume $A$ and $B$ and $NOT C$ and show this leads to a contradiction.  (Thus $NOT C$ can not exist with $A \& B$ so $A \& B \implies  C$)

3) contrapositive:  Assume $NOT C$ and show this leads to NOT $A$ OR NOT $B$. (Thus NOT $C$ can only exist with either NOT A or NOT B so NOT $C$ can not exist with both $A$ and $B$ so $A \& B \implies  C$.

The three methods are all compatible.  2 and 3 are very closely related and as NOT A OR NOT B is a contradiction to A AND B, 3 can be seen as a subset of 2. (That is; assuming A and B and NOT C and concluding NOT A OR NOT B is an adequate contradiction.  But 2 can be demonstrated by *any* contradiction.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prove $A \implies B$, you assume $A \not \implies B$ and show this leads to some contradiction, so it is impossible. Since the impossibility is only based on the assumption $A \not \implies B$, this assumption must be incorrect. Hence $A \implies B$.

Comment: So it suffices to show that A and NOT B leads to a contradiction? Further, if the claim is $A$ and $B$ imply $C$, then I can show $A$, $B$, and NOT $C$ leads to a contradiction?

Comment: $A \not \implies B$ means A and NOT B are both simultaneously possible.  You show that  A and NOT B lead to a contradiction.  So A and NOT B are not simultaneously possible.  So whenever you have A you can't have NOT B.  So you must have B.  So $A \implies B$.  (BTW you have also proven $NOT B \implies NOT A$, as whenever you have NOT B, you can not have A.  These are equivalent statements.  $A \implies B$, $NOT B \implies NOT A$, $NOT (A \& NOT B)$, (A \& B) $ OR $ NOT A$ are all equivalent statements.)